# Seeing poor real-time performance on Linux GPIO toggle test using SCHED_FIFO

Tags: linux, real-time

I'm experimenting with some jitter timing tests by toggling a GPIO line and observing the waveform on an oscilloscope.  My kernel is compiled with `PREEMPT_RT`.  I was hoping that changing the scheduler for the process to `SCHED_FIFO` would reduce the jitter, but it doesn't seem to have made much of a difference.  The code is below.  Is there anything I am doing wrong in trying to get realtime performance from this code?

```
// Program to test Linux timing jitter by driving GPIO output via sysfs interface.
// In this variant, the scheduler is changed to SCHED_FIFO.

#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sched.h>

#define GPIO_TO_PIN(bank, gpio) (32 * (bank) + (gpio))

int main() {
    char buf[128];
    struct sched_param schedp;

    const int pin = GPIO_TO_PIN(1, 24);

    int fd = open("/sys/class/gpio/export", O_WRONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open export for writing!\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    int bytes_written = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", pin);
    write(fd, buf, bytes_written);
    close(fd);

    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/direction", pin);
    fd = open(buf, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open gpio direction for writing!\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    if (write(fd, "out", 3) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set direction!\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", pin);
    fd = open(buf, O_WRONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open gpio value for writing!\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    // Change scheduler to SCHED_FIFO.
    schedp.sched_priority = 99;
    if (sched_setscheduler(0, SCHED_FIFO, &schedp)) {
        perror("sched_setscheduler");
    }

    while (1) {
        if (write(fd, "1", 1) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write value!\n");
            return(-1);
        }
        usleep(500);

        if (write(fd, "0", 1) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to write value!\n");
            return(-1);
        }
        usleep(500);
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, it is wrong to expect RT performance from user-mode code. How much jitter are you expecting and how much are you seeing?

Comment: I see about a 10% jitter in the squarewave when the system is idle, but if I run commands then I can sometimes see it not toggle for a few ms.  I thought the point of the PREEMPT_RT addition was so that you could do real-timeish code in userspace?

Comment: @user43995 Somewhat. Linux isn't a realtime OS, so there's still no guarantees. Also, by default, 5% of of a second can still be used by lower priority tasks and preempt your "realtime" task (see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-rt-group.txt). You'll also be bound by the kernel tick rate, though with the usual 1000Hz tick rate, that could account for only 1ms.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasons why you might not see a decent real time performance. First of all, you should check on the OSADL Website http://www.osadl.org. First thing to evaluate is if you have a realtime capable system as such.

Check [here](https://www.osadl.org/Realtime-Preempt-Kernel.kernel-rt.0.html#testingandusing) for a howto on testing real time performance.

Also I see that you are writing to a GPIO. I am not totally familiar with this, but I guess there is some sort of kernel driver/thread that is responsible for the device. You need to make sure that this thread also gets RT shed by something like chrt -f -p 99 < pid >

Also consider nanosleep over usleep.

Although pretty late, this may give you some hints to start of.